# Site promotion - list of audio-related blogs

Tags: discussion, promotion

I'm borrowing this idea from the folks over at [meta.cooking.se](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196/get-the-word-out-food-blogs-and-press).  Let's build a list of Audio Recording and Production blogs that we can contact about this site.  The goal is two-fold: hopefully the bloggers will join and participate as experts, and hopefully they will help in promoting the site.  **Do you know anyone at these sites? And if so, would you drop them a note?** If you have contacted anyone of note, add them here and add your name underneath so we can have a concise list of who's been contacted. Please edit this list as you see fit.

**Blogs**

- [John Wilborn](http://johnwilborn.wordpress.com/audio-recording/)
- [Audio Recording Tips From Kathie](http://sonysoundford10.com/)
- [HomeTracked](http://www.hometracked.com/)
- [Home Recording Blog](http://www.recordingreview.com/blog/)
- [The Stereo Bus](http://thestereobus.com/)
- [Projectopia](http://projectopia.wordpress.com/)
- [Manuel Marino](http://manuelmarino.com/)
- [Musical Banter](http://www.musicalbanter.com/)
- [Home Studio Tips](http://homestudiotips.com/)
- [Chitt Productions](http://www.chittproductions.com/)
- [Pro Sound Blog](http://www.prosoundblog.com/)
- [Tight Mix Blog](http://tightmixblog.com/)
- [Create Digital Music](http://createdigitalmusic.com/)

**Forums**

- http://homerecording.com/bbs/ ([Lennart Regebro](http://meta.audio.stackexchange.com/users/223/lennart-regebro))
- http://www.recordingproject.com/bbs/ ([Lennart Regebro](http://meta.audio.stackexchange.com/users/223/lennart-regebro))
- [Logic Pro Help](http://www.logicprohelp.com/)
- [Studio-Central Forums](http://studio-central.com/phpbb/index.php)
- [KVR](http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/)
- [Sound on Sound](http://www.soundonsound.com/forum)
- [Cakewalk Forums](http://forum.cakewalk.com/)
- [REAPER Forums](http://forum.cockos.com/forumdisplay.php?f=20) - posted a [thread](http://forum.cockos.com/showthread.php?t=78980)
- [Gearslutz](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/forums/)
- [Steinberg Forums](http://www.steinberg.net/forum/)
- [Native Instruments Forums](http://www.native-instruments.com/forum/)
- [Home Recording Forums](http://forum.recordingreview.com/)

**Other sites**

- [Metafilter](http://metafilter.com/)
- [Fark](http://www.fark.com/)
- [Delicious](http://www.delicious.com/url/4b9ed3c9b90cafaf06a681493ae956d8)
- [Digg](http://digg.com)

  - Three questions dugg [here](http://digg.com/tomwij)

Comment: anyone know how I can make this community wiki?

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention and ask them to change it to a community wiki.

Comment: I've pushed for the site at two forums: http://homerecording.com/bbs/ and http://www.recordingproject.com/bbs/, where I used to be active earlier.

Comment: Submitted this site to DMOZ, three nice top Qs to [Digg, Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/TomWij) (please Digg, 1), site to Delicious (5) and site to StumbleUpon (1).

Comment: @TomWij: Feel free to update the question with your links.

Answer (score 1):

[Jeff challenged me](http://meta.audio.stackexchange.com/questions/135/proposal-to-seed-the-site-with-useful-questions-and-answers/136#136) to provide a list of online audio recording communities. Here is a quick sampling (on 22nd Apr 2011) of the activity at a few of the ones listed above:

- http://www.gearslutz.com/board/ Posts: 5,047,776, Members: 130,931, Threads: 455,918,
- http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/ Posts: 4,496,115 Members: 221,525
- http://homerecording.com/bbs/ - Posts: 3,592,282 Members: 98,388 Threads 313,544
- http://forum.cakewalk.com/ Posts: 2,086,820 Members: 63,132 Threads: 209,789
- http://www.native-instruments.com/forum/ - Posts: 818,960 Members 213,403 Threads 126,479
- http://www.soundonsound.com/forum Posts: 749,548 Threads: 91,944, Members 88,422
- http://forum.cockos.com/index.php Posts: 716,017, Members: 28,045 Threads: 73,738,
- http://studio-central.com/phpbb/index.php Posts 545,653 Members 31,019, Threads 74,926
- http://www.recordingproject.com/bbs/ Posts 532,602 Members 9,349
- http://recording.org/ Posts 364,891 Members 41,835 Threads 47,911
- http://www.logicprohelp.com/ Posts 357,794 Members 44815
- http://forum.recordingreview.com/ - Posts: 256,497 Members 72,126 Threads 35,296
- http://line6.com/community/ Posts: 253,856 Threads: 54,972
- http://www.steinberg.net/forum/ Posts 47,480 Members 6,538 Threads 6,896

  - (which replaced http://www.cubase.net/phpbb2/ Posts 822,376 Members 48,506)

... I could go on but hopefully you get the picture. There are a *lot* of people asking and answering questions on audio recording every day on the internet